# Something is wrong with the locks on my PC at work

Tags: command-line, 16.04, google-chrome, lock

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. Whenever I try to run most of the programs I get an error related to locks. Even when I open a terminal window I get an error related to locking.

For example, when I open a terminal window I get the following:

```
zsh: locking failed for /network/directory/user/.zsh_history: operation not supported: reading anyway
```

If I start Google Chrome:

```
[20499:20499:0124/120628.318341:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(280)] Failed to create /network/dir/user/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock: Operation not supported (95)
[20499:20499:0124/120628.318525:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1413)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
```

Starting an app called Gajim:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gajim.py", line 530, in <module>
    check_paths.check_and_possibly_create_paths()
  File "/usr/share/gajim/src/common/check_paths.py", line 335, in check_and_possibly_create_paths
    create_log_db()
  File "/usr/share/gajim/src/common/check_paths.py", line 79, in create_log_db
    '''
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked.
```

Comment: Long shot: Is "/network/directory/user/" a CIFS share? If so your CIFS version is not compatible with the one you use in Linux and you need to supply a `vers={number}` to your mount.

Comment: Are all partitions mounted "read/write"? Do you have a broken harddrive?

Comment: To be honest I don't know if its a CIFS share and all partitions are mounted read/write. I don't have a broken hard drive. In matter of fact, when I do export home=/dir/on/my/disk then the problem goes away

Comment: I don't know lowercase home environment variable. So I assume you are talking of uppercase HOME. That in fact should point to your home directory. Otherwise programs started by you would try to write their runtime data to somewhere else in the filesystem where you may have no write access. This could lead to such error messages.